# How am I expected to use v8::SetNativesDataBlob?

Tags: c++, embedded-v8

Investigating a segfault in my code,  looking for `GetBuiltinsCount` in the [V8 source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/external/v8/+/bleeding_edge/src/natives-external.cc) leads me to this comment:

```
/**
 * NativesStore stores the 'native' (builtin) JS libraries.
 *
 * NativesStore needs to be initialized before using V8, usually by the
 * embedder calling v8::SetNativesDataBlob, which calls SetNativesFromFile
 * below.
 */
```

**How am I, the embedder supposed to use `v8::SetNativesDataBlob`?**

The [d8 interpreter](https://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/d8.cc) does call this method, but it's not at all clear what it's doing and why.
The basic samples do not  call this method.

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace? It doesn't start in your code? Have you tried running a debug build in a debugger to confirm the crash isn't actually because of something you did? If you build with extra warnings enabled, do you get any warnings?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I left out the frames showing my own code, they are not interesting. The crash literally happens on the line where I call `Isolate::New()`. This is a debug build, compiled warning-free. I will run in gdb now to see if that gives me any useful info, but I doubt it. This code is running fine on some systems but not others.

Comment: Running "fine on some systems but not others" is a typical sign of *undefined behavior*. Try enabling even *more* warnings when building, like e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on GCC.

Comment: That's good advice. I'll try with `pedantic`. I already have `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: And if you don't find anything wrong with your code, even after stepping through your code line by line to make sure it works, there *could* be a bug in V8. It's big and complicated and complex, and all big, complicated and complex pieces of code have bugs in them, so don't be afraid to report it to the V8 project as such if you can't find anything in your code. Even better would be if you could pinpoint what and where in their code the problem is. Also, when reporting bugs it's even more important to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then when asking questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit over a year later, I find myself back at this question, and now I know the answer.

You can compile V8 with external startup data ("snapshot") or without.

If you compiled *with* snapshot data, call `V8::InitializeExternalStartupData` as shown in the [Hello World example code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/4.8/samples/hello-world.cc). You don't call `v8::SetNativesDataBlob` directly.

Otherwise, the solution is to compile *without* snapshot data. Then, you don't need to call either of the aforementioned functions at all. Here's one answer on [how to configure this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009180/385094) in your build process. Note, using snapshot data decreases process start-up time.